# Phase plane of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have ODE course in my university this year. Our teacher gave us a problem in the first lesson and said that if we solve it, we'll have an advantage in the exam. Probably the task is too difficult and he is joking. So here it is:

We have an ODE: $$y^\prime = y^2+x$$ 
I need to prove:

1. Phase lines have a vertical asymptotes in the left and on the right.
2. Upper part of x=-y^2 is asymptote. 
   (I add a pic of it)
3. Prove that there is only one phase curve without vertical asymptote(Toughest question).

Any ideas, links and explanations are welcome. Thank you.

[image: some ugly drawing]

Comment: Since this is verging on an exam question for your class, we shouldn't be doing the exercise for you. But thank you for your honesty! I'm not sure I understand how your professor is using the words "phase line" and "phase curve." But, by the way, you can certainly integrate this differential equation explicitly. Have you done so?

Comment: Are you sure this is an $x,y$ plane instead of a $y,y'$ plane? Either way, parts 2 and 3 don't make sense to me. Part 1 is obvious if you solve the equation, but I wouldn't call the solution a "phase line". I agree with Ted.

Comment: @TedShifrin  I think phase line/curve basically means phase portrait. We've only used "separation of variables" method so far. Btw first two questions is just to help to answer the third one, which solution will give an advantage. But I'm just interested how difficult it is and which methods should I use?

Comment: @mr_e_man I've tried to draw isoclines and some solutions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isocline

Comment: An isocline $y^2+1=\text{constant}$ is a pair of horizontal lines. This still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh! There is a misprint. I'm sorry. It is $y^\prime = y^2 + x$

Comment: Well, that explains the $y^2+x=0$ asymptote. Good grief!